# Webpack doesn't properly generate external sourcemap

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, uglifyjs, source-maps

I have a lot of jsx, es6 code and I want to compile, minify all my stuff.  Also I want get **external source map** for my production build.

But I have some kind of problem with webpack - it's generate a perfect inline sourcemap, but external not good. It's also generate them, but in my browser (Chrome 45.0.2454.85) I look nothing about sourcemap. What am I doing wrong?

It's my webpack.config.js

```js
var config = {
  watch: false,
  context: __dirname + '/src/app',
  entry: './app.jsx',
  devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.js.map'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }, {
      test: /\.js/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }],
    noParse: [
      'axios',
      'jquery',
      'js-cookie',
      'lodash',
      'react-bootstrap',
      'react-router',
      'reflux',
      'react-highcharts'
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: '{file}.gz',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      regExp: /\.js$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Why are you using `jsx-loader` when Babel supports JSX too and is not the official approach? Have you tested it without `UglifyJsPlugin`? May be worth doing to verify.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It has been old comment in my code. I'm using babel loader that tell my config. About UglifyJsPlugin. I tested build process without UglifyJsPlugin and get the same result.

Comment: Oh haha, that's what I get for skimming :P So have you liked in the sourcemap file itself? What do you get in the external file? Is it the browser that can't read the file, or webpack not creating the file right?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Webpack create external source-map file, and that shipped to browser, but that contained source-map of the uglified file!